# iPadOS Keyboard CMD+Z calls UndoManager's undo selector twice?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipados

I'm having an issue with `UndoManager` which might be an iPadOS bug, but could also be my mistake.

I have a simple test app. One button performs an action, which increments an int by 1 and registers an undo with the system `UndoManager`. Another button manually calls `undoManager.undo()`, which undoes the last action until no more actions on the undo stack remain. And the overall app is a first responder with the system, so hitting `CMD+Z` should also trigger the undoManager to call `undo()` *once per CMD+Z press*.

Here's some code.

The UIHostingController subclass that allows becoming first responder:

```
class FirstResponderHostingController<Content: View>: UIHostingController<Content> {
    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool { true }
}
```

SceneDelegate, where I pass in the system undo manager:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)

            let model = MyObject(undoManager: window.undoManager)
            let contentView = ContentView(model: model)

            window.rootViewController = FirstResponderHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

And my SwiftUI view and associated model:

```
class MyObject: ObservableObject {
    var undoManager: UndoManager?
    var state: Int = 0

    init(undoManager: UndoManager? = nil) {
        self.undoManager = undoManager
    }

    func registerAction() {
        state += 1
        undoManager?.registerUndo(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(performUndo), object: nil)
        print("registered action - state is \(state)")
    }

    @objc func performUndo() {
        state -= 1
        print("performUndo called - state is \(state)")
    }

    func undo() {
        print("undo() called")
        undoManager?.undo()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: MyObject

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 16) {
            Button(action: {
                self.model.registerAction()
            }) {
                Text("Register an Action")
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.model.undo()
            }) {
                Text("Manual Undo (Not from Keyboard)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So for example, if I tap "Register Action" twice, and then "Manual Undo" three times, the output is what I expect - the state was incremented twice, then decremented twice, and the last undo() does nothing because the undo stack is empty:

```
registered action - state is 1
registered action - state is 2
undo() called
performUndo called - state is 1
undo() called
performUndo called - state is 0
undo() called
```

But if I tap "Register Action" twice, and then hit `CMD+Z` on the iPad keyboard, I expect the state to be incremented twice and decremented only once, with one call to `performUndo`, but instead `performUndo` is still called twice:

```
registered action - state is 1
registered action - state is 2
performUndo called - state is 1
performUndo called - state is 0
```

Am I using the system UndoManager incorrectly somehow, or is this a bug?

*Update:* The above is with Xcode 11.3.1 and iPadOS 13.3. Using the latest Xcode 11.4 beta 2 and iPadOS 13.4 beta 2, the double-undo no longer occurs. Seems fixed!